# Error at uploading my React Native/Expo app on Google Play Console

Tags: android, react-native, apk, expo, google-play-console

Months ago I uploaded an alpha app that I created using Expo on React Native. I build the app with the version 1.0.0 in app.json. The people involved with the project tested it, I improved it with some other things and we concluded it's ready to go to production.

The thing is Google Play Console returns error when I try to upload it. According to the message (number 2 in the below print), it says (in Portuguese) "You already have an APK or Android App Bunble with version 1 code. Use another code". What does that mean?

[image]

Basically, I uploaded it, improved it and now, want to upload it again with the new things.

I tried to upload it in alpha again, beta, build the app again with version 1.1.0 in app.json but, same error message. Has this version 1 code nothing to do with the version in app.json?

In the below print, we can see the main panel, where there is just one release, which is the alpha one. Any help would be great. Thanks for now.

[image]

------------------ EDIT -----------------------

According to an answer, I thought it would be good to put the print of app.json. I hid some private fields. As you can see, the version is 1.0.0, but I tried building a 1.1.0 and 2.0.0 version app. None of them solved the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems like your new app has a `versionCode` that conflicts with the existing app.

go to `YOUR_APP/android/app/build.gradle` and search for `versionCode`. increase the number by 1, recompile your `.aab` or `.apk` and upload again.

**UPDATED**

`versionCode` is missing. Can you add it like this?

```
“android”: {
  “versionCode”: 2,
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks kenmistry for answering. The problem is, as I said, the app was created with Expo, which abstracts React Native. That means there is no folder called android in my project. There is a file called app.json and there is a version field. I tried increment it and build the app. It didn't work. I'm going to edit my question with a print of this file. The problem persists, unfortunately.

Comment: Well, i dont see any `versionCode` under `android` for the json file. Can you can add that and make it a `2` without any periods?

Comment: That's it! Adding versionCode as you said worked. Thanks a lot kenmistry!